# phpMyAdmin Fatal Error - require(): Failed opening required

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, xampp

I just installed XAMPP on my Windows 7 system and I get the following error when I open phpMyAdmin from path `localhost/xampp/`

```
"Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required './libraries/session.inc.php' (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\common.inc.php on line 367".
```

I'm not able to understand what this means. Please suggest a way to fix this!

Comment: It can't open the file /libraries/session.inc.php, if you search our system is it there?

Comment: Nope. It isn't :( I wonder what screwed it up. Do you suggest a fix or a complete reinstall?

Comment: Something hasn't taken, I would try again.

Comment: Did a reinstall. Still wondering what could have caused it at the first place. Thank you very much, Richard :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no proper workaround for this, only a complete reinstall worked. I tried a lot of things, trust me!